# STM32F446RE Nucleo LD1 slow blinking red and I'm not sure why

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, nucleo

I'm using the STM32 using the power from a voltage regulator circuit that generates a stable 3.3V onto the board. Before that, when I tried to upload my program from the Arduino IDE to test it, it went perfectly well with the serial monitor showing the data i needed and all. But when I disconnected it from my laptop and change the power to the external battery, the LD1 on my board was blinking slowly with red. I've tried to read the datasheet and it said:

> Slow blinking Red/Off: at power-on before USB initialization

but I'm still having a hard time understanding it because the voltage and the wirings on my board is theoretically correct, and I don't see anything wrong either with the program because it's a simple code as below:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Ensure this baud rate matches your HC-05's configuration
  
  while (!Serial) {
    ; 
  }

  Serial.println("Bluetooth Test Started");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Hello from STM32F446RE");
  delay(2000);  
}
```

I would really appreciate the help from anybody.

I've tried resetting my board but nothing seemed to change. I'm just wondering if this is normal or not. If so how can I make my board run normally with an external power supply.

Comment: Maybe it expects to be able to initialize USB before doing anything? It looks like the MCU does a lot of work before the "void setup()" is executed, more than before usual main() function. It's probably stuck at USB init stage, because it's not connected to a USB host. Try with another USB host (laptop), it could need special drivers installed on the host (try without driver and with driver if that's the case). I'm not sure in any of this, never programmed an STM32 with Arduino IDE, but this is what I could gather from the info you provided. Give it a shot, see if anything happens.

Comment: On these boards usually the debugger chip is providing clock for the main MCU. If you are only powering 3V3, the debugger mcu might end without power and 411 witout clock -> it might run at 8MHz internal clock as it fails to switch to the external and probably skips PLL settings

Comment: see https://github.com/Shikhargupta/MCU-Development-STM32/blob/master/Resources/STM32-Nucleo-64-pins-schematics.pdf  the regulator for STLink chip is powered from U5V or E5V and has +3V3_ST_LINK rail. It should work with E5V/Vin